# System backup not working

Tags: backup

I attempt to make a full system backup through the admin but it just says please wait for a couple minutes and then doesn't appear to have made a backup. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should do some debuggin. Enable your logs in system->configuration->developer->log settings -> enabled: yes. Then run the backup and check your log files in var/log and var/report. Post what you find here. You could also uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); in your index.php around line 73, this will show you an error message when something goes wrong. If still nothing comes up add this line at the bottom of your .htaccess SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true" - this will show more logging. Be aware you don't to this on production as your customer will be able to see errors too

Comment: From var/log: 
2015-11-09T21:52:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): Current implementation not supported this type () of backup.

Var/report didn't seem to have any info relating to the backup. I uncommented that line but didn't get an error message

Comment: Can you tell me something about your hosting environment, magento version and the modules you use? Also what kind of backup you are trying to create. There should be some backup type within type() like type(db)

Comment: 1.9.2.2 and no modules yet. I'm trying to make a system backup before I start adding modules and a theme

Comment: The built in backup tool doesn't work particularly well and should be avoided. You are best using command line to backup your store.

Comment: Are there any good free modules that provide backups?

Comment: you have to use backup from server management panels, or scripts like these https://gist.github.com/magenx/07503580876a372b2b54 , never use magento built-in backup because it will break your shop.

Comment: You mean I should do the backups from my web host (cPanel) instead?

Answer (score 2):

The backup system doesn't work. Avoid using this tool. Backup your files using backup from MYSQL, ftp or your file system.